# Caixa de Seleção instantania

Tags: javascript, html, formulário

Fiz uma caixa de seleção e queria que aparecesse a escolha em um formulário assim que escolhido. Porém a opção só aparece se eu der enter após escolher a opção ou se escolher uma opção e ir mudando com a seta do teclado.
Há alguma maneira de assim que a pessoa clicar na caixa e escolher a opção desejada ele já apareça no formulário?

Código:

```html
<html>
<body>

Cliente <select id='nome' type='text' value='' onkeyup="insere()" />
    <option></option>
    <option>joão</option>
    <option>Camila</option>
    <option>Marcelo</option>
    <option>Iago</option>
    <option>Willian</option>
    <option>Neide</option>
    <option>Takaro</option>
</select>

<p>CLIENTE: <span class="cliente"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">

var cliente = document.getElementById('nome');

var cliente1 = document.getElementsByClassName('cliente')[0];

function insere() {
 
    cliente1.innerHTML = cliente.value;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

É só trocar o evento de **keyup** para **onchange**:

```js
var cliente = document.getElementById('nome');
var cliente1 = document.getElementsByClassName('cliente')[0];

function insere() {
  cliente1.innerHTML = cliente.value;
}
```

```html
Cliente
<select id='nome' type='text' value='' onchange="insere()">
  <option></option>
  <option>joão</option>
  <option>Camila</option>
  <option>Marcelo</option>
  <option>Iago</option>
  <option>Willian</option>
  <option>Neide</option>
  <option>Takaro</option>
</select>

<p>CLIENTE: <span class="cliente"></span></p>
```

> **- onkeyup:** é executado todas as vezes que uma tecla for pressionada, geralmente é utilizada em elementos de entrada de texto como `input` e `textarea`.
>
> **- onchange:** é executado todas as vezes que uma `option` for clicada dentro de um elemento `select`.

**Da uma arrumada no seu Html tbm, tem tag `p` sem fechar, o `select` tbm está errado.**

Comment: não havia aprendido sobre o oncharge vlw a dica